# Addon/Script: Register custom user properties

Tags: python, add-on, customization

Is there a way to register custom user properties for example a filepath the user can set under `User Preferences > File`?

Even better would be the possiblity to register a whole new tab in the user preference menu but that is not necessary if it would be complicating my effort.

Answer (score 1):

The filepath properties are stored in `bpy.types.UserPreferencesFilePaths`, which does not support custom properties (only ID types and Bones do).

Even if it was possible, you couldn't make a property show still - addons can't overrule default layout scripts.

You can use [**AddonPreferences**](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html) however, as long as the properties are not supposed to be stored in every individual .blend you work with. AddonPreferences show up in the *User Preferences > Addons* tab, below the addon info (the addon entry needs to be expanded).

Comment: It's even better if they are not stored within the blend file. I want it to be installation wide, not portable (the artist's name and the default export path)